# Vim findfile function usage?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for an example of how to use the findfile function in a vim script to search upwards recursively for a file, specifically using a wildcard.

Whenever I include a wildcard character as part of the first function parameter this doesn't seem to work.

For example, with the following directory structure:

```
~/MyProject/
    Test.sln
    src/
      Test.cs
```

If I run the following function, while editing the file Test.cs with pwd set to ~/MyProject/src

```
function! Test()
   let a = findfile("*.sln", ".;")
   echo a
endfunction
```

findfile appears to return nothing. However, if I modify the function to remove the widcard as follows:

```
function! Test()
   let a = findfile("Test.sln", ".;")
   echo a
endfunction
```

It does what I would expect.

I've tested this on both ubuntu and windows and I see the same behavior on both. Am I doing something wrong here, or does findfile just not support wildcard characters? A lack of support for the wildcard character seems like a fairly strange omission. It seems like I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: :help file-searching lends me to think that it tries to support globbing, but this seems to be wrong in practice.  Is this a bug in vim?

Comment: From `vim` [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching): *The usage of '\*' is quite simple: **It matches 0 or more characters**.  In a search pattern this would be ".\*".  Note that the "." is not used for file searching*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using wildcards I think the `glob()` and/or `globpath()` functions are what you're looking for.  See `:h glob()` and `:h globpath()`.

Comment: I think you're correct, it looks like findfile doesn't support wildcards, and glob is what I'm looking for. I've taken this approach and wrote a loop to iterate through the parent directories until I find what I'm looking for. This does what I need, thanks!

Comment: Here is what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/towerofnix/040fbe4437eeaa572c0f35ea169b3565

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with external (fast) `find`

```
function! Test()
  let l:list=system("find .. -maxdepth 1 -name \*.sln")
  echo l:list
endfunction
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I think this only works in the case where the *.sln file is in the parent directory. I was specifically looking for a solution that will recurse up the directory structure until it finds a matching file (which is how I thought findfile would behave). For example if I was editing a file in the directory ~/MyProject/src/innersrc I don't think this solution would work.

Comment: @actf I see, what do you think about looping that finds, `..` then `../..` until you get it?. Or e.g. experiment with `expand('%:p:h')` that can get you the full path of the current file.

Comment: Yea I think this is the best approach. It looks like getting the working directory, then looping through the parent directories and searching with a wildcard via glob() does what I need.